# JPA Criteria API: entity type expression

Tags: jpa, jpql, criteria-api

JPQL has entity type expression, e.g.

```
SELECT e
FROM Employee e
WHERE TYPE(e) IN (Exempt, Contractor)
```

Does criteria API have entity type expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `Path.type()` creates an `Expression` corresponding to the type of the given path. You can then create class literals using `CriteriaBuilder.literal()` for use in comparison expressions.

Comment: can the path be Basic or Embeddable type? or type() is applicable to Entity type only?

Comment: I must say I have never tried using type expressions for anything other than entities, but I don't think it would even make sense. JPA stores type info for inheritance hierarchies of entities only, and I can't really think of a case when you wouldn't know the type of a path expression.